Cygwin Perl won't load DLLs anymore, perhaps due to a failure to convert cygwin paths to Windows paths
I'm suddenly unable to run any Perl scripts under Cygwin.  Every script I try to run crashes like this:
phil@TAICHI /cygdrive/h/bakE/new/virChecked
$ findFiles -s . -t /cygdrive/D/data-comp/text -u /cygdrive/E/new/virChecked/text -d -a .3
Can't load '/home/phil/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi/auto/Win32/File/File.dll' for module Win32::File: No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/5.36/x86_64-cygwin-threads/DynaLoader.pm line 206.
 at /usr/local/bin/findFiles line 24.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/bin/findFiles line 24.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/findFiles line 24.

phil@TAICHI /cygdrive/h/bakE/new/virChecked
$ pushd /home/phil/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi/auto/Win32/File/
~/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi/auto/Win32/File /cygdrive/h/bakE/new/virChecked

phil@TAICHI ~/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi/auto/Win32/File
$ ls -l File.dll
-r-xr-xr-x 1 phil None 178K Jul 14  2021 File.dll*

Sometimes perl won't open File.dll; sometimes it won't open IO.dll.  In either case, the DLL is always exactly where Perl is looking for it, with world read privs; but Perl won't load it.
Line 206 of Dynaloader.pm is
my $libref = dl_load_file($file, $flags) or croak("Can't load '$file' for module $module: ".dl_error());

A comment near the start of Dynaloader says:
The load function that dl_load_file() calls may require an absolute pathname.

I can't find where dl_load_file() is defined.  It isn't in Dynaloader.pm; and the only module Dynaloader includes is Config, which also doesn't have it, and includes no other files.
I suspect that some Perl module has changed, with the result that dl_load_file doesn't convert Cygwin absolute pathnames to Windows absolute pathnames. I tried reinstalling Perl 5.36.3-1, but it didn't help.  I also made a new Cygwin installation and installed Perl 5.40, but it behaved the same way.
Questions:

Is anyone else currently able to use Perl in Cygwin using the lastest Cygwin packages?
Any idea what might have changed recently to make Cygwin Perl unable to use full Cygwin paths?
Where can I find a Cygwin perl distribution prior to Perl 5.32?

POSTSCRIPT added October 13:  I've gotten a lot of comments, but not one person has yet answered the simple question of whether THEY currently have a working version of Cygwin Perl.  Please, someone, if you have a recent Cygwin Perl that still works, say so.

Re "perhaps due to a failure to convert cygwin paths to Windows paths", This is a Cygwin build of Perl and it must use Cygwin paths

The error code for loading a dynamic library (dll or so) can be for a dependency of the library. Since the DLL exists, it's probably a DLL used by that DLL that can't be found. Use debugging tool to inspect to the DLL's dependencies.

@ikegami, I used "perl -d", and got a crash on a "use IO::Handle ();" in Seekable.pm, saying, "Attempt to reload IO/Handle.pm aborted."  "cpan install IO::Handle" crashed with "Can't load '/home/brek/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi/auto/IO/IO.dll' for module IO: No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/5.36/XSLoader.pm line 94."  That file also exists, but "perl -d -e 'use IO'" just resulted in "Attempt to reload IO.pm aborted." , with no further traceback. So I can't find out more with perl -d. Know another Perl debugging tool that might work?

first thing to do is verify the perl your scripts running in is the one you think it is

perl -d runs a Perl script in the Perl debugger. It doesn't inspect the dependencies of a DLL.

Show us the result of uname -a, and which -a perl. Then confirm that you are doing installs using a setup.exe recently down loaded from cygwin.com. If not, use it and reinstall perl and any installed perl modules. Make sure to install any perl modules you need from cygwin setup in preference to cpan due to cygwin customization.

@Doug Henderson, I did a fresh install of cygwin using setup-3.5.x86_64, which is one version behind.  I installed exactly one cygwin perl, and 'which perl' said /usr/bin/perl.  I can't run uname on that now because I already deleted that cygwin, and won't re-install it right now bcoz I'm in the middle of transferring everything to new hard drives.  Do you currently have a running Cygwin Perl?  If so, which version of Perl is it?

Re "not one person has yet answered the simple question of whether THEY currently have a working version of Cygwin Perl.", Because the question is absurd.  For starters, you already showed that Cygwin Perl works. And you're the one who hasn't done what they should. You still need to find out which DLL is missing.

@ikegami, I showed that Cygwin Perl /doesn't/ work for me, not that it works. Can you please recommend a DLL debugger?  I've found two, but both are freeware that is not open-source, and I generally don't install freeware unless it's open-source, for security.

No, you showed that loading some module doesn't work. Perl itself worked.

Re "Can you please recommend a DLL debugger?", No, or else I would have told you.

Looks like Win32::File isn't provided by the Cygwin package manager.  You probably installed it yourself, upgraded Perl, then didn't reisntall Win32::File. The DLL in question is probably the DLL for the earlier version of Perl.

Oh yeah. The module that's failing is installed in your home dir. That's surely what happened. Note the lack of version component in the path of the DLL. Stupid INSTALL_BASE doesn't add it, resulting in these problems (instead of module not found).

I think the tool you need is ldd. ldd /home/phil/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi/auto/Win32/File/File.dll should confirm the problem

ikegami, you're right. Searching for other Perl DLL problems, I found that the Cygwin command 'cygcheck' will list the dependency tree of a DLL, and that showed that DLLs in my home directory are trying to load perl5.32 DLLs that are no longer there.  Thanks!

Examining the DLL with cygcheck identifies the problem.

$ cygcheck
/home/phil/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi/auto/IO/IO.dll
...
cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygperl5_32.dll
$ perl -version
This is perl 5, version 36, subversion 3 (v5.36.3) built for
x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi (with 6 registered patches, see perl -V
for more detail)
$ ls /bin/cygperl5*
/bin/cygperl5_36.dll*

I installed some packages into my home directory instead of the standard location, then upgraded perl. Since these were self-installed modules, the Cygwin installer did nothing to update them when I used it to upgrade perl.
But they were still on the module search path (@INC) even though they were linked against the DLL from Perl 5.32, which caused the problem at hand.
Re-installing those modules using the new version of Perl addressed the problem.

Re "Between Nov 14 and 30 2023, my Cygwin changed from storing its DLLs under my home directory, to storing them under /bin", You keep coming up with the wildest conclusions. No. It would always have been under /bin. Between Nov 14 and Nov 30, you upgraded Perl 5.32 to 5.36. Period. The location of the Perl DLL did not change.

@ikegami  When you wrote "Cygwin", you meant the Cygwin installer.  When I wrote "Cygwin", I meant the Cygwin installation as a whole, including the cpan executable., which is what defaulted to storing DLLs in my home directory.  At the time I wrote that, I hadn't figured out that it was only packages I had added using cpan which were stored under ~.

Re "When you wrote "Cygwin", you meant the Cygwin installer.", Nope. My only three mentions of "Cygwin" were "Cygwin build of Perl", "Cygwin Perl" and "Cygwin package manager". I was obviously not talking about the installer in any of the three cases.

Nope. cygperl5_*.dll was always in /bin. It was never in your home dir

Re "I still don't understand why /usr/bin is an exact copy of /bin, down to the timestamps.", If your installation is like mine, /bin isn't a directory, but a symlink to /usr/bin. You're accessing /usr/bin in both cases, so of course they have the same contents.

Fixed your question and removed all the irrelevant talk about /bin and /usr/bin

Sorry, second last comment is wrong. I opened up my Linux VM instead of my Cygwin VM. In Cygwin, /usr/bin doesn't even exist on the drive. It's a completely virtual hard link of /bin. As a hard link, it's literally only one directory with two names. Just like / and /bin/.. are two names for the same directory.

I made a new cygwin installation just for using Perl, and did not install Perl, nor anything that included Perl (which was restrictive and extremely tedious, as the Cygwin installer doesn't list package dependencies or say which package required an auto-added inclusion).  Then I installed Strawberry Perl on the system, outside of Cygwin.  I didn't have to set any environment variables.  Cygwin automatically detects and uses Strawberry Perl if no other perl is present.
But this turns out not to be AT ALL satisfactory.  Strawberry Perl can't read Unix paths; and it can't read DOS paths.  It requires all filenames be given in a bastard Unix/DOS hybrid format; e.g., "E:/data/foo".  I'd have to rewrite nearly every Perl script I have to get it to work; and then I'd be unable to use them on Unix machines.
(DELETED: I'd still like to know if anyone has gotten the latest Cygwin Perl to work.)
